# Simplenews newsletter unsubscribe page- Access denied

Tags: 7, users, emails

I am using Simplenews newsletter module on my Drupal-7 website to send newsletters, but when you click on the unsuscribe link, the user gets an access denied page-you need an account to view this page etc.
Where can I make this page visible to all users or/and change what this page says?
 For example, instead of Access denied to show an image or say "Error" or something else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The access arguments for that page are `subscribe to newsletters`, meaning that you need to grant that permission to anonymous users, in order to allow them to unsubscribe without logging in.

Here's how to do that:

1. Navigate to `/admin/people/permissions`.
2. Find "subscribe to newsletters" item.
3. Grant the permission to anonymous users.

Note: I just told you how to allow to do it for everyone. You need to evaluate if this fits your website and workflows.

Comment: You're welcome! Glad it helped.